# Where can I find information/code for a match making site? (Not necessarily dating)

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, zend-framework, codeigniter

Can anyone point me in the direction of a site, blog post, etc... that gives clear and concise examples/information about creating a match making site. I should state one point before you bite my head off:

This is NOT for a dating website. It's for a site that will attempt to match potential visitors to our site with other like minded visitors and pros on our site. It's more match making, and potentially social networking, but not exactly. Good examples/information would be algorithms used or code samples. My language of choice is php but I'm not averse to ruby on rails either.

Thanks to all who can contribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map their preferences onto a multi-dimensional space and then use the [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between the two subjects [Cartesian coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinates) to determine how "matched up" they are. Then you just need to find the subjects with the shortest distances and these are your suitable matches.

Comment: This is spot on Chris! Thanks for the answer. Now I just need to convert it into the code of my choice. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at http://www.socialengine.net

You need to purchase a license, but you can get a 1 month demo. Its pretty complete (almost like you're own facebook).

Its built on Zend Framework and allows you to extend it with modules.

Comment: Hey Jacob, this is a great start, but I'm more interested in some info regarding how you would go about matching up two individuals based on information they provide. i.e. Think Match.com but extremely dumbed down. How does one go about finding out if Sam would be good friends with Jake? Ohhhh well They both enjoy camping, bike riding, blondes, etc... I was hoping for an algorithm of some kind to assist with tracking it down.